# Filter array based on the keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array:

```js
let array = [
  'Hello 1» (Foo_Test-Editable)', 
  'Hello 2» (Foo_Test-Editable)', 
  'Hello 3»  (Foo_Test)', 
  'Foo_Test_4'
];

let searchKeyword = 'Foo_Test';
const result = array.filter(f => f.indexOf(searchKeyword) != -1);
console.log(result);
```

Rules to find:

- array item should contain only `Foo_Test`, not `Foo_Test+...` plus some variations

Desired result is:

```
let result = [
    'Hello 3»  (Foo_Test)'
];
```

How to filter using the above rule?

Comment: You are searching for `Foo_Test` and your code works, it returns all three lines because all three of them contain `Foo_Test`. Now, what you are doing wrong, can be two things. In order to get the desired output, you can either search for something more specific like `(Foo_Test)`, or modify your code so it excludes, for instance, lines with `Foo_Test-followed-by-another-word`. You need to define precisely the goal and the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the keyword to a regex...

```js
let array = [
    'Hello 1» (Foo_Test-Editable)', 
    'Hello 2» (Foo_Test-Editable)', 
    'Hello 3»  (Foo_Test)', 
    'Foo_Test_4'
  ];
  
  let searchKeyword = /Foo_Test[^-|_]/;
  const result = array.filter(f => searchKeyword.test(f));
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks man! It works! Thank you very much! You are awesome! Ninja man! Super!:)

Answer (score 1):

Add the parentheses around `"Foo_Test"` to distinguish it.

```
let srch = "(Foo_Test)"
```

```js
let arr = [
    "Hello 1» (Foo_Test-Editable)",
    "Hello 2» (Foo_Test-Editable)", 
    "Hello 3»  (Foo_Test)", 
    "FooText"
]

let srch = "(Foo_Test)"

const result = arr.filter( f => f.indexOf(srch)!= -1)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: sorry man, I can't do it. Thanks for your response. Maybe you have another suggestion?

Comment: @Learner what are your constraints?

Comment: array item should contain only `Foo_Test`, not `Foo_Test+...`

Comment: @Learner `Foo_Test` will always include the first three strings, bc they all have that substring in them

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code is working , output was 3 array because all of them contained search value **Foo_Test**

```
(3) ["Hello 1» (Foo_Test-Editable)", "Hello 2» (Foo_Test-Editable)", "Hello 3»  (Foo_Test)"]
```

so add parentheses around (Foo_Test) to distinguish it from other, which will output specific value

```
(Foo_Test)
```